# How to implement AWS autoscaling policies using spinnaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, spinnaker

I am trying to play with spinneker with aws cloud-driver..
I have created a pipeline and can add capacity - Min: 1, Max: 7, Desired: 2
I am wondering how / where to specify autoscaling policies to scale up and scale down the instances based on the metrics..

Answer (score 5):

In Spinnaker, scaling policies are configured on an ASG itself, but not in a pipeline. You can configure the scaling policies by clicking on the ASG in the "Clusters" tab, then look under "Scaling Policies" in the details panel on the right.

Once an ASG, e.g. `myapp-v000` has some scaling policies, if a pipeline creates a new ASG in the same cluster, e.g. `myapp-v001`, Spinnaker will create copies of the scaling policies from `myapp-v000` and apply them to `myapp-v001`.